# applicationShouldTerminate: not called when system restarts

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-mojave

I have to run some code when the app is about to terminate. applicationShouldTerminate: runs when quit is selected from the menu or when I press Cmd Q but not when I restart the mac. 
Is there a way to force applicationShouldTerminate when a user tries to restart the mac? Or is it another function being called in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Your app might have [Sudden Termination](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfo?language=objc#1651129) enabled.

> macOS 10.6 and later includes a mechanism that allows the system to log out or shut down more quickly by, whenever possible, killing applications instead of requesting that they quit themselves.

...

> Debugging tip
>
> You can determine the value of the sudden termination using the following LLDB command.
>
> `print (long)[[NSClassFromString(@"NSProcessInfo") processInfo] _suddenTerminationDisablingCount]`